# Unable to install MySQL on ubuntu (elementary os)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to install mysql on my laptop but during installation I get this error:

```
131217 15:59:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131217 15:59:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131217 15:59:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131217 15:59:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131217 15:59:42 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
131217 15:59:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131217 15:59:42 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131217 15:59:42  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131217 15:59:43 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 1595675
131217 15:59:43 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'log_slow_verbosity=query_plan'
131217 15:59:43 [ERROR] Aborting

131217 15:59:43  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
131217 15:59:44  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
131217 15:59:44 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: errors were encountered while processing: mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
podproces instalovaný post-installation skript vrátil chybový status 1
Žádné apport hlášení nebylo vytvořeno, protože již byl dosažen MaxReports
dpkg: nesplněné závislosti zamezily konfiguraci balíku mysql-server:
mysql-server závisí na mysql-server-5.5; avšak:
Balík mysql-server-5.5 zatím není zkonfigurován.
dpkg: chyba při zpracovávání mysql-server (--configure):
problém se závislostmi - nechávám nezkonfigurované
Žádné apport hlášení nebylo vytvořeno, protože již byl dosažen MaxReports
Nastavuji balík             libmariadbclient18 (10.0.6+maria-1~precise) …
Zpracování spouštěčů pro balík libc-bin …
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't currently switch languages so I hope you will not get confused.
I tried to purge previous installation and do it again but there is no difference.

Could anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Offtopic for SO, try [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install the original MySQL on a system that's previously had Percona Server installed.

This error:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'log_slow_verbosity=query_plan'
```

....suggests that you have a configuration in a `my.cnf` file somewhere that sets that option, but that option `log_slow_verbosity` isn't supported in MySQL; it's a Percona extension. See [here](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.1/diagnostics/slow_extended.html?id=percona-server%3afeatures%3aslow_extended_51&redirect=2#log_slow_verbosity) for documentation on that variable.

To fix the problem, find the `my.cnf` file that the server is trying to use, probably in `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and either delete it to go with default settings during installation, or simply remove the line containing `log_slow_verbosity`.

Answer (score 2):

After you get that error edit your **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** and comment **log_slow_verbosity=query_plan** string
Then reinstall mysql again with
**sudo apt-get install mysql-server**

Found solution [here](http://druss.co/2015/01/fixed-error-usrsbinmysqld-unknown-variable-log_slow_verbosityquery_plan/)